# Pods not found while using kubectl port-forward

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I want to forward the ports

```
kubectl port-forward ...
```

But for this I need to find out the name of pods, I run the command

```
kubectl -n main_sp get pods
```

Getting a list:

```
NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
main-ms-hc-78469b74c-7lfdh         1/1     Running   0          13h
```

I'm trying

```
kubectl port-forward main-ms-hc-78469b74c-7lfdh 8080:80
```

and I get

```
Error from server (NotFound): pods "main-ms-hc-78469b74c-7lfdh" not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to mention the namespace too while using port-forward:

```sh
$ kubectl port-forward -n main_sp main-ms-hc-78469b74c-7lfdh 8080:80
```

To port-forward a pod:

```
$ kubectl port-forward -n <namespace> <pod-name> <local-port>:<target-port>
```

To port-forward a pod via service name:

```
$ kubectl port-forward -n <namespace> svc/<servic-name> <local-port>:<target-port>
```